# change event to set focus on button was working suddenly its not

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some simple jquery such that when a drop down box is selected I set the focus to a button.  This was working fine and now I noticed it is no longer working.

```
$("#MainContent_dialogSubProjectPMddlManager").on('change', function (evt, params) {
    $("#MainContent_btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM").focus();
     return false;
});
```

The drop down id is `MainContent_dialogSubProjectPMddlManager` the button id is `MainContent_btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM`.  I have verified all of this in the console.  Event setting the focus in the console works fine.  But when I make my drop down selection the button is not set to focus.

What I am trying to do is set the focus on the button so the user doesn't have to mouse over to click the submit button.  In this way they could simply hit the enter key...But that isnt working as expected and I cannot understand why.

Here's the markup for the drop down:

```
<asp:DropDownList data-placeholder="Select Sub Project..." class="chosen-select" ID="dialogSubProjectPMddlManager" ToolTip="Select Sub Project Manager..." runat="server"
></asp:DropDownList>
```

And the markup for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM_Click" Text="Submit" ToolTip="Submit / Save changes?" />
```

I'm using the chosen library but that should not matter, here is the rendered html:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$dialogSubProjectPMddlManager" id="MainContent_dialogSubProjectPMddlManager" title="Select Sub Project Manager..." data-placeholder="Select Sub Project..." class="chosen-select" style="display: none;">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="257">Test, Test</option>
        <option value="258">Test2, Test2</option>
    </select>
```

And for the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM" value="Submit" id="MainContent_btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM" title="Submit / Save changes?" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

Comment: any error in console.

Comment: can you post the relevant html

Comment: Do you append the HTML after the page is initiated?

Comment: What do you consider as relevant?  Do you want the markup for the drop down?

Comment: @JonH yes, the markup of the dropdown as well as the button, but not ASP.NET one, but *rendered HTML*

Comment: @Aditya - Same result using document.on

Comment: Works correctly here http://jsfiddle.net/qD7YE/

Comment: Just tried it and seems like it does not work with JQuery 2.0.x

Comment: Try this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tRZ4j/3/). If you change JQuery version to 2.0.2 it stops working.

Comment: It is working for jQuery 2.0.2 as well .. http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/qD7YE/1/

Comment: @Aditya - nope, your fiddle not working for me.

Comment: Results of testing - Chrome - works always, IE 11, Opera - 2.0.2 not working but 2.0.x (edge) and 1.9.1 working.

Comment: We're using 2.0.3 jquery and it doesnt seem to work in Chrome/IE 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case you can try `OnChange` client event of `DropDownList`.

```
<asp:DropDownList data-placeholder="Select Sub Project..."
    class="chosen-select" ID="dialogSubProjectPMddlManager"
    ToolTip="Select Sub Project Manager..."
    runat="server"
    OnChange="dialogSubProjectPMddlManagerChange()">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM"
    runat="server"
    OnClick="btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM_Click"
    Text="Submit"
    ToolTip="Submit / Save changes?" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function dialogSubProjectPMddlManagerChange() {
        $('#<%= btnSaveDialogSubProjectPM.ClientID %>').focus();
    }
</script>
```